# Alternative to Psensor?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, software-recommendation

I am looking for an alternative to Psensor. I am running 16.04 LTS on my mid-2010 MacBook Pro and am wanting to monitor temperature and such. I have been using Psensor, and after seeing my CPU regularly sitting at the 90-100+ C range I fired up HTOP to see why my CPU was getting used so much. Looks like it was usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core....... that was running consistantly at ~50% CPU and then Psensor was around 20%. I think xorg is the GFX driver used for my nvidia card?

Anyways, as it turns out when I shut down Psensor and kill its tasks everything goes back to where it should be and the xorg process might take a tenth of a percent every couple secs. So it seems as though Psensor is the problem as to why my computer turns into a plate of lava...

Long explanation, maybe I can change its configuration or something? Or just use something different that isn't such a resource hog. What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Psensors` is a graphical front end to `lm-sensors`. If the CPU usage is purely down to a problem with `Psensors` then you can install an alternative front end. I recommend `XSensors`.

Alternatively you can monitor the values returned by `lm-sensors` in real time simply by using the command `watch sensors` in a terminal.